# 'BluetoothSocket' is not defined

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I am trying to set a bluetooth server on my raspberry pi using python. I have get the error **'BluetoothSocket' is not defined**, however, I followed a sample code on the [bluez repository](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/blob/master/examples/simple/rfcomm-server.py).

However, I have installed the required libraries.

```
from bluetooth import *

server_sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)

port = server_sock.getsockname()[1]

uuid = "94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"

advertise_service( server_sock, "SampleServer",
                   service_id = uuid,
                   service_classes = [ uuid, SERIAL_PORT_CLASS ],
                   profiles = [ SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE ], 
#                   protocols = [ OBEX_UUID ] 
                    )

print("Waiting for connection on RFCOMM channel %d" % port)

client_sock, client_info = server_sock.accept()
print("Accepted connection from ", client_info)

try:
    while True:
        data = client_sock.recv(1024)
        if len(data) == 0: break
        print("received [%s]" % data)
except IOError:
    pass

print("disconnected")

client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
print("all done")
```

This is my version:

```
pi@TolotraPi:~ $ sudo apt-get install python-bluez
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-bluez is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 161 not upgraded.

pi@TolotraPi:~ $ sudo apt-get install bluez
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
bluez is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 161 not upgraded.

pi@TolotraPi:~ $ python --version
Python 2.7.9
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you, by any chance, named the script you are working on `bluetooth.py`? If so, your `import` statement is importing your script, which doesn't include a `BluetoothSocket` class.

Comment: @kindall thank you so much. I would have never known without your comment